# Is there a way to create a leader for a mercenary band?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing an old version of Crusader Kings 2 (2.1, I think). At one point, Paradox updated the game to include more mercenaries and holy orders. As I was the Irish King at the time, I had the option to create the Irish Band. However, I didn't realize its potential, and as it used up one of my duchy slots, I somehow got rid of it.

At present time, the Irish Band, as with a few others, exists, but has no leader. This means I can not vassalize it.

Is there an in-game method to add a leader to the band?

Alternatively, I assume I can use the console command `give_title` to hand it to a random character (and then vassalize him), but I'm currently looking for a non-console solution.

Comment: I'd assume not. Holy Orders/Mercenaries select their new leader when the previous leader dies. If you've somehow glitched them into having no leader, this will never happen.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think too. I was thinking to give the title to myself, and then create a random new vassal, but I assume that is only posible for baronies and bishopries.

Comment: I think you should be able to hand off the title for the mercenary band to someone else. IIRC some people had to do this when they somehow inherited a holy order or another, which disabled marriages for the character they were playing.

Comment: @Affine The twist is, that I currently do not control it. No one does; it has no leader. I wanted to know if I could dynamically create a leader, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I would suggest would be to do something along the lines of what [this guide](http://crusaderkings-two.wikia.com/wiki/Vassalizing_Mercenary_Companies) suggests. Bait the mercenary company by hiring them then running out of gold to pay them until they rebel. This will force them to be a landed character. Probably won't work, but it's worth a shot. Otherwise, the answer is no, there is no way to do this without using console commands, because all diplomatic actions that may bring them under your control so you can appoint a ruler requires a ruler to begin with.